# Issue with Regex Replace?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to perform a Regex.Replace in C# for the following string:

```
   Regex.Replace("Some text template and word to {{replace}}", "({{replace}})", value)
```

I'm running into a issue where once in a blue moon the value doesn't get fully replaced.
For example the template comes out to: "...Word to {{replace}}bla2#5".
The value is randomly generated 12 character string containing Uppercase, lowercase, numbers, and special characters (!@#$%&?). When the above error happens only 10 characters appear so I'm suspecting a escape character or special combination of characters that's messing up the replacement.

Any possibilities will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any reason you are using magic templates and not string interpolation?

Comment: The literal dynamic replacement pattern must be preprocessed - `"({{replace}})".Replace("$", "$$")` to avoid parsing `$0` or `$&` as whole match backreference, or `$1` as Group 1 backreference.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You probably mean `value.Replace("$", "$$")`. This is because [substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions) sequences in the replacement string are interpreted.

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes, sorry, I posted the comment at midnight.